# Build a class instance from elements in a list

Tags: scala

I want to build an instance of a class Something by calling the function foo on this calss for every element in  a list. e.g.

```scala
val list = List(1,2,3)
```

should result in a call with the same effect as:

```scala
val something = somethingBuilder.foo(1).foo(2).foo(3)
```

Is there a way to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you can do :

```scala
val list = List(1,2,3)
val something = somethingBuilder
list.foreach(something.foo)
```

Comment: Ah so simple! thank you. Was thinking about it functionally whereas the library im using is obviously not a functional one

Comment: You're welcome ! On this subject, this could be interesting : https://alvinalexander.com/scala/iterating-scala-lists-foreach-for-comprehension

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you care for the returned value of your builder call. Then following code will print `Builder(6)`:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)

case class Builder(val i: Int){
  def build(j: Int) = Builder(i+j)
}

val finalBuilder = list.foldLeft(Builder(0))(_.build(_))

println(finalBuilder)
```

If you only care for the side effect, maybe Rafael's solution is more adequate (although using the `foldLeft` will of course also trigger the side-effect).

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solution.

```
val lst = List(1,2,3,4,5)
class Builder(val i: Int){
   def Foo() {
     println("Value is initialized: " + i)
   }
}
lst.map( a => new Builder(a).Foo())
```

But the disclaimer, it does generates the list of empty lists as a side effect

```
print(lst.map( a => new Builder(a).Foo()))
```